# [cedet]: how to add a new ede target?

Tags: emacs, cedet

I can't find an easy way to add ede targets to my projects. I am looking for the way to add an install target or even a test target to run unittest.

How do you do that with ede-project-manager ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using one of the EDE projects that supports it, the operation can be found in the menu.

Step 1: Open a file in a project directory.
Step 2: Choose the menu item "Project->Project Options->Add target"

It will ask if you want to add the current file into that target.

You can also do:

```
M-x ede-new-target RET
```

Some EDE project types don't support this concept.  Most notably the built-in Emacs and Linux project types, or the ede-cpp-root project, which is a quick hack to support the basics of the Semantic parsing infrastructure.

Comment: Ok for that. But how can I tell EDE I want a target "install" which will call 'install' to deploy my stuff (install mybin /usr/bin) ?

Comment: Someone would need to write a new target class to generate the new rules for the project.  I suppose a "write it yourself" target would be the easiest thing to add to EDE to make this (or anything else) work now.  If you join the CEDET mailing list we can work out the details there.

You can also just write the Makefiles yourself and then point EDE at the project a different way.

Comment: Thank you Eric. I will join CEDET mailing list (I have other questions ;)).